# How can i order data by specific String Field

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore

i have the following get method

```
  FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('comments').limit(5)
        .orderBy('commentDate',descending: true)
        .get(const GetOptions(source: Source.server)).then((value){
          //outputs
          today
          yestrday
          oldest
          oldest
          oldest
           
       });
```

in previous method i am sorting comments according to the latest .

one of the fields is `commentOwnerId : Lx33AN0RwDEWzO7T3xQV`.

Perhaps the owner of the comment is not the most recent , However, I want to show it as a priority over the rest of the documents .

```
  FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('comments').limit(5)
        .orderBy('commentOwnerId ',descending: true) // here i am stack 
        .orderBy('commentDate',descending: true)
        .get(const GetOptions(source: Source.server)).then((value){
          //outputs
          myComment (yesterday)
          today
          oldest
          oldest
          oldest
           
       });
```

i notice if the `commentOwnerId` field is `Boolean` instead of string value so it work as expected
but of course i cannot use `Boolean` since i need to chick if it was `==` my id or no then descending it to true if it was mine .

How could i handle it ?

Comment: I see that smarter google people than me are at work here, but I don't see a way to do this with a single query. I'd make two queries, one to find comment's by me, one to find comments not by me, both sorted by date, both with a limit. I'd concatenate those results (my comments first) and slice to the limit.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm doing now but it's a bit scary if there's a pagination going on.. there's probably more than a 10 of my comments by me so a lot of logic to make the queries proportionate to the list

Comment: Ah, if it's paging, how about always do the date sorting with a cursor, then in the UI for the current page, sort again, always giving primacy to customerId == me?  If all of the results on that page are you or none of them are, that's just how it is on the date sorted page the user is on ?  In other words, don't mention anything about ids in the query. Do that on the client.